# Getting podcast flash movie to work in MHT file

Tags: javascript, flash, mhtml

I've got an MHT file from Adobe Contribute.  I'm trying to get a flash file working in the MHT doc.  It's a podcast so it shows the player then pulls the mp3 file, its not one file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>    
var so = new SWFObject("mp3player.swf", "mp3player1", "225", "175", "7", "#CCCCCC");
so.addVariable("file", escape("2006-11-13.mp3"));
so.useExpressInstall('expressinstall.swf');
```

So I can't just import the file, it works with javascript to make it show up.  How can I get this to work in the MHT file? The code snippet works in a regular HTML file but when I put it in the MHT file, it just comes up blank.  Maybe the MHT doesn't read the js?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Flash and javascript can be embedded into MHT files because MHT is a container format, like zip.

Try using full urls for "mp3player.swf" and "2006-11-13.mp3". Relative urls are resolved using the Content-Location header or the Base html tag. Adobe Contribute may have altered either one to point to itself.

You can open and edit a MHT file in a text editor.